# Java POST API call with Postman using @PathParam and List object

Tags: java, rest, postman, path-parameter

For my project requirement, I created an API in JAVA which accepts 2 parameters like below

```
getSimilarImages(@PathParam("rbcCode") String rbcCode, List<String> fieldNames)
```

I am new to POSTMAN application.

Could anyone educate me on how do I call this API using POSTMAN.

Below is my controller file code.

```
@Controller
@Path("/services/AIMLServices")
public class AIMLController {

private static Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(AIMLController.class);

@Autowired
AIMLService aimlService;

@POST
@Path("/getSimilarImages/{rbcCode}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String getSimilarImages(@PathParam("rbcCode") String rbcCode, List<String> fieldNames) {
    LOG.info("IN getSimilarImages() API");
    System.out.println("IN getSimilarImages() API rbcCode=" + rbcCode + " No of fields=" + fieldNames.size());
    return aimlService.getSimilarImages(rbcCode, fieldNames).toString();
}
```

}

I tried with this below setup in POSTMAN,

```
Doing a post call with the below URL by passing rbcCode
http://localhost:4990/dev/acs/admin/fm/api/services/AIMLServices/getSimilarImages/BELK

And under Body raw type as JSON, I am passing list like below
["a","b","c"]
```

but it did not work.

Comment: what the response in postman ?

Comment: have you tried adding rbcCode in your path? like `@Path("/getSimilarImages/{rbcCode}")`

Comment: have you tried @RequestBody annotation for your list of strings?

Comment: Can you screenshot your postman and share all settings you have done?

Comment: tried, that too not working

Comment: Where is the path variable in your `@Path` `@Path("/services/AIMLServices")` and `/getSimilarImages/`?

Comment: https://ibb.co/fYMgJ33  This is how i am trying to call through Postman.

Comment: I tried this also. @Path("/getSimilarImages/{rbcCode}")

Comment: can you please check web.xml what is the path defined over there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to add `@ResponseBody` on your method and use @RequestBody for your list parameter.

Also as others mentioned, you need to specify your path param in the `@Path`

Comment: Thanks @madz and everyone, I am able to call the api now after adding RequestBody and Consumes

Comment: @Aadi Cheeersss